# Property initializers vs old way of initializing property .Can you clarify

Tags: c#, c#-6.0

googled but could not find an explanation of usage for property initializers

Could somebody tell me if below code is the same?are properties that uses property initializers only instantied once?

what is the difference between these 3 ways of initialize a list in terms of efficiency and best practice

```
    1)  private List<Address>Addresses
        {
            get
            {
                return addresses ?? (addresses = new List<Address>());
            }
        }

    2)  public List<Address> Addresses{ get; set; } = new List<Address>();

    3) within constructor  Addresses= new List<Address>()
```

thanks for clarifation!

Comment: Your examples are rather poorly thought out, and riddled with inconsistencies. Example 1 is private, read-only, and lazily initialized, and example 2 is public, read-write, and not lazy. I'm hoping that's not intentional, because it just makes for a needlessly confusing question.

Comment: @BoltClock I am sorry my question is not clear ,however you totally failed to understand the point. my point is I dont understand what property initializer do under the cover HENCE the 3 ways of doing it, totally different .Bottom line what do I achieve using a property initilzer that is all.

Comment: @developer9969, what exactly are you looking for? Lazy initialization? Initialization of a read-only property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Examples 2 and 3 initialize the property as soon as each instance is created.

Example 1 initializes the property *lazily*; it does this by initializing the backing field only at the first invocation of the property getter (when the backing field is still uninitialized). It's entirely possible that the backing field remains uninitialized for the entire lifetime of a given instance provided that instance's `Addresses` property is never accessed.

Whether or not lazy initialization is more efficient depends entirely on the property and how it's going to be used.

The pre-C# 6 equivalent of example 2 is *not* lazy initialization, but the following:

```
public List<Address> Addresses { get; set; }
```

... with initialization being done in the constructor. Declaring and initializing an auto-implemented property in the same statement is new to C# 6.

Comment: One more case: `private List<Address> addresses { get; set; }` `public List<Address> Addresses => addresses;`

Comment: @Tân Nguyễn: Why a private read-write property and not a backing field?

Comment: I usually use the way to handle some case like `OnlineUsers`. Ex: `OnlineUsers` cannot be changed when user creates a comment or post a new thread to forum. But, it can be assigned in `AccountController`. Of course, this question doesn't mention about `static`.

Comment: @BoltClock thanks for your explanation! Not knowing what a property initializer does i thought "does it lazily initialize?" mm by you confirmed it just initialize the same way as you had done in a constructor. so its only initialized when the class is created regardless how many times the property is called .correct?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, do not use concrete implementation of class for property, use interface (IList, for example). Secondly, I prefer to initialize property as your Addresses inside default constructor and then call this constructor from another.
For example:

```
public class MyClass1
{
    public IList<MyPropertyClass1> Property1{get; protected set;}
    public MyPropertyClass2 Property2{get; protected set;}
    ...

    public MyClass1()
    {
        //I initialize Property1 by empty List<T>=> internal logic will not crashed if user try to set Property1 as null.
        Property1=new List<MyPropertyClass1>();
        Property2=default(MyPropertyClass2);
        ...
    }

    public MyClass1(IList<MyPropertyClass1> property1, MyPropertyClass2 property2)
        :this()
    {
        if(property1!=null)
        {
            Property1=property1;
        }
        if(property2!=default(MyPropertyClass2))
        {
            Property2=property2;
        }
    }
}
```